# Simple PHP page protect script where password only authenticates the first 3 characters?

Tags: php, passwords

I'm setting up a very simple page "protected" by a password, up to there all OK, but we would like to have it where only first 3 digits/characters used get verified.

The page is not something that is top secret or anything, we only want it this way to avoid "general" people (without the knowledge on how to get in) from accessing the content.

So for example at the moment we have:

```
$password = "NBX9785";
```

And then the content that is being hidden is hidden as follows:

```
        <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["password"]) && ($_POST["password"]=="$password")) {
    ?>
```

But what we want is to just have the NBX count and not the numbers or rest of the password, which will basically allow us to give out more codes without the need of extra coding.

Is this possible and is there an easy way to do this?

To push it even further is it possible to set it to have say NBX99D24 where NBX are fixed, but 99, D and 24 are numbers and a letter respectively?

Comment: [`substr_compare($_POST['password'], $password, 0, 3, true) == 0`](http://us.php.net/substr_compare) for the simple case, [`preg_match('#^NBX[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}$#', $_POST['password'])`](http://us.php.net/preg_match) or similar for the other.

Comment: Did you even bother reading about PHP string functions?

Comment: Thanks DCoder, I have no PHP knowledge and that helps me loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first three characters from the string and compare

```
if(mb_substr( $_POST["password"],0,3) === mb_substr($password, 0, 3))
{
    // Your content here
}
```

OR

```
if(strpos($password, mb_substr( $_POST["password"],0,3)) === 0) 
{
    // Your content here
}
```

Also all is here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Thanks infinity, perfectly works for the first three characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use perhaps str_len() function?

```
$text = "this.is.a.test.text";
echo substr($text, 0,3);
```

The above code, displays the first 3 characters, so you can manipulate the data thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the NBX, however are you sure you want to do a user verification this way? It isn't a vary secure method and using a database is a lot more secure.

If you do want to do it this way, infinity's answer would fit well.

In regards to your last question, you could make it up from 4 variables:

```
$password="NEX";
$password.="99";
$password.="D";
$password.="24";
```

Alternatively, the numbers can be integers (remove the quotes),

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated. We know it's not secure, but it's basically a "password" to give people access to a special page (no critical data, or anything secret). The password is just there to give them a sense of needing the code to get in.

Comment: Ok, best of luck with your site!